# Use Easy Mock Objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I am working on a Junit Test where I need to work on Easymock  and  Class objects together to rub the test.

Following is my code snippet

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    request=EasyMock.createMock(SlingHttpServletRequest.class);
    response=EasyMock.createMock(SlingHttpServletResponse.class);

}

@Test
public void testImage() {

RequestContext ctx = new RequestContext();  

// RequestContext and RequestContext Util are both classes defined in Project

    expect(RequestContextUtil.setupContext(request,response)).andReturn(ctx);

    // This line is throwing an error , so I am not able to add replay or verify method

}
```

I tried to see an example where I can use Easy mock and Class object together , I could not find that is suitable for my case. Can anybody point me to an example ?

Comment: what you are trying to do won't work because your code does not use a mock but a call to a static method which cannot be mocked (since it's not called on a mock). If you give more context what and how you want to test maybe someone will be able to help you find a workaround.

Comment: I have a Util class which stores request context of application and other set of properties related. Util class use slingrequest and sling response object. I am trying to create a junit test on this Util class (one of its method).

Comment: well without seeing the whole code it's hard to advice you anything but you might either have to stop using mocks and set everything up properly or refactor your codebase so you can use mocks.

Comment: I guess if easy mock does not provide something like this then I might have to re factor

Comment: well there are ways around this, but I always feel dirty when I mention PowerMock on SO: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic This isn't good practice and you should feel bad for using PM :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
private MockHttpServletRequest request;
private MockHttpServletResponse response;

 @Before
 public void setup() {
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
}

    @Test
    public void testImage() {
      //here you don't need to `expect` or `reply` 

     // `request` and `response` is mock now. 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock a static method invocation using EasyMock. 2 solutions:

- Extract the static invocation to a different method in your SUT and test a partially mocked version of your SUT (mocking only the new method where the static invocation is done). [Partial mocks using easymock](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/org/easymock/IMockBuilder.html).
- As someone mentioned above, use PowerMock and mock directly the static invocation.